# Post 500 (Internal Server error) ajax in codeigniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, post, internal-server-error

I have a problem to sending data with ajax, when i click button save to sending data to database. but when i push F12 the error show

```
POST http://[::1]/sys-web/admlogin/manufacture/addmanufacture 500 (Internal Server Error)
send @ http://[::1]/sys-web/assets/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js:4
ajax @ http://[::1]/sys-web/assets/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js:4
save @ http://[::1]/sys-web/admlogin/manufacture:374
onclick @ http://[::1]/sys-web/admlogin/manufacture:507
```

CI Controller

```
public function AddManufacture()
{

    $data = array(

        'manufacturing_name' => $this->input->post('manufacturing_name'),
        'address' => $this->input->post('address'),
        'email' => $this->input->post('email'),
        'telephone' => $this->input->post('telephone'),
        'join_date' => $this->input->post('join_date')
    );
    $insert = $this->m_manufacture->save($data);

    echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE));
}
```

CI Model :

```
function save($data)
    {
        $sql = $this->db->insert($this->table, $data);
        return $sql;
    }
```

CI View :

```
    function save()
 save_method = 'add';
        {
            $('#btnSave').text('saving...'); //change button text
            $('#btnSave').attr('disabled',true); //set button disable
            var url;

            if(save_method == 'add') {
                url = "<?php echo site_url('admlogin/manufacture/addmanufacture')?>";
            } else {
                url = "<?php echo site_url('admlogin/manufacture/editmanufacture')?>";
            }

            // ajax adding data to database

            var formData = new FormData($('#form')[0]);
            $.ajax({
                url : url,
                type: "POST",
                data: formData,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                dataType: "JSON",
                success: function(data)
                {

                    if(data.status) //if success close modal and reload ajax table
                    {
                        $('#modal_form').modal('hide');
                        reload_table();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.inputerror.length; i++)
                        {
                            $('[name="'+data.inputerror[i]+'"]').parent().parent().addClass('has-error'); //select parent twice to select div form-group class and add has-error class
                            $('[name="'+data.inputerror[i]+'"]').next().text(data.error_string[i]); //select span help-block class set text error string
                        }
                    }
                    $('#btnSave').text('save'); //change button text
                    $('#btnSave').attr('disabled',false); //set button enable


                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                {
                    alert('Error adding / update data');
                    $('#btnSave').text('save'); //change button text
                    $('#btnSave').attr('disabled',false); //set button enable

                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: So what have you set $config['base_url'] to be in your config file /application/config/config.php?

Comment: You need to set your base url example `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/yourproject/';`

Comment: my $config['base_url'] = '';

Comment: and the error say " Failed to load http://localhost/sys-web/admlogin/login: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://[::1]' is therefore not allowed access. "

Comment: Here is a fun thing to do to check everything... var_dump($_SERVER) What do you get for 'HTTP_HOST'  and 'DOCUMENT_ROOT' ?

Comment: where i should to take that script

Comment: Anywhere that makes sense!